# Python venv programmatically

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-venv

We are trying to add venv functionality to our python project ie when one runs project an venv is created in project path and project runs on that venv.
For this to work we used vurtualenv's create environment  method and activatethis.py  the method creates venv ,
However when project runs it still uses host machine packages. Instead of using venv ones
Am I doing anything wrong..is it possible to do this??
PS: I have tried both site-packages true and false in create environment method .. however to no help

Adding more info:
Commands used are

```
venv_dir = os.path.join("path to project")
virtualenv.create_environment(venv_dir)
execfile(os.path.join(venv_dir, "bin", "activate_this.py"))
```

Also updated path environment variable to include bin of venv

After this I expect my code (after this) to run in virtual environment.

I am not using any ide and expect the code to create venv at runtime

Using python 2.7

Is there any other way to run project in virtual environment at run time without any ide in Ubuntu server environment.

Comment: Can you show the exact sequence of commands you're using to run the code from the venv?

Comment: This question is way too vague to warrant a decent answer. Please elaborate on what you have done and how you accomplished it, some code would be useful as well. First thing that comes to mind for doing something like this would be to generate an `sh` configuration script to run before your project is run, but without any more details from you, that is not very helpful.

Comment: are you running through console? Does your script properly set up the environment? Can you supply your code? Need more info

Comment: Yes I am not suing any ide and running code via console..

Comment: [Pipenv](https://docs.pipenv.org/) may do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided enough information for us to come up with a solution to your exact problem, although I will do my best to help you out.

You should not be creating a `venv` every time you run the project, which it sounds like you are doing. This is essentially creating a new interpreter every single time you run your project. If you're using a decent IDE, such as PyCharm, you should be able to set this up properly through the project settings.

There are plenty of tutorials out there regarding setting up `venv` and `virtualenv` on your computer, and given that we don't know much about your system, your best bet is doing some further research.

Essentially, you need to

- Create a `venv` for the project (and a new one for each project you make from here on out, unless you want to use the machine's interpreter)
- Set the project interpreter to the `venv` you just created. Place any external libraries within `...\venv\Lib\site-packages`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response I have update the question ...however what we are trying to achieve is to run the project in an isolated environment which is created at runtime.         Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: @AshishKarki Quite frankly, I see no reason to ever want to do that, but if you must, go right ahead, I can't stop you.

Comment: @MatthewMeeker one use case for this would be for continuous integration where multiple environments are created on the fly. In a similar vein to what tox is used for.